# Cyborging in Paranoia 25th Anniversary Edition

Tags: paranoia

Me and my group were starting a game of Paranoia when one of the players, whose character is a fairly high ranking Corpore Metal member, asked if she could be a cyborg. The upgrade she suggested was reasonable except for the fact that it was extremely obvious and I was not sure if cyborging was legal in Alpha Complex. After the game when I looked through the rulebook (Paranoia: Troubleshooters) and I was not able to find anything on cyborging except for a short paragraph in the Secret Skills section.

Is cyborging legal in Alpha Complex? How advanced is the cyborging technology?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Comment: Two words that will ensure endless fun for the Paranoia GM when a player wants to be a cyborg: *"Safety Recall"*

Comment: "Of course cyborging is legal, Citizen! As long as you've filled out form [DELETED FOR SECURITY REASONS] and filed it with your local CPU office 3-27 cycles before receiving your prosthesis. You *did* remember to do that before getting your arm replaced, didn't you?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would add that can be legal on certain moment (great! more machines! less Humans!) and then the Computer (You) decide that is no longer legal (oh wait... other thinking machines rather than me? No way... Phew phew phew!).  That's the way Paranoia works..

---

To clarify the Paranoia Style is that something could be legal and illegal at the same time, you dont have to stack into black or white, the fun comes when you puzzle the players, if they start trusting that something is ok probably will start exploiting it, and then is the sweetest moment to change the rules/mind of the Computer. So he asks between two possibilites, I say the third is the most fun!

Comment: Not to mention that it may be perfectly legal according to the Computer sub-node in one sector and completely commie-mutant-traitor-scum behaviour in the next sector over, where a different sub-node thinks it's Really Not On. For extra bonus, ensure that the group straddle the boundary multiple times during the scenario.

Comment: You're suggesting that the Computer has flaws? That's treason... please vaporize @Vatine on sight citizens...

Comment: You could have the Cyborg be a piece of experimental equipment, so they can make there own decisions and role play themselves but the equipment officer is responsible for them, with the relevant forms and information to be tracked, checked and triple checked. maybe he Cyborg is also given a role, loyalty officer maybe, the chance of clashes between the borg and the equipment officer is great. In fact, I am loving this idea :). it is up there with an adventure i ran where one of the players had had a version of friend computer downloaded into its head, without anyone else knowing.

Answer (score 13):

This is Paranoia. The first rule in Paranoia is there are no rules. The whole rule book is nothing but a guide. If it sounds cool and you want cyborgs in your Alpha Complex then they are legal. If you think they should be illegal then they are.

***You are*** the computer, you make the rules. You decide what is legal and what isn't. Paranoia is a whole exercise in rule 0.

Now, remember, this is Paranoia. So one of your players wants to be a cyborg? To me that sounds most fantastic and illegal, let them have it and let it be subtle so most people don't notice they are a cyborg. Now how can you screw them over in the most comedic way possible? Perhaps they gain a stutter when speaking to the computer? Perhaps they make whirring and hissing noises when they over exert?

Let one of your other players know someone is a cyborg. Give them a secret mission to find and kill the cyborg. Now with the flaws above, how long till they start shooting at each other? Give them plenty of opportunities and get it all on camera! Let the hilarity ensue.

Remember, this is Paranoia and you are the Computer.

Answer (score 5):

Becoming cyborgs is one of Corpore Metal's major goals—hell, it's *their name*. Some sort of cover story might be helpful, e.g., they work for R&D, were fitted with experimental equipment, are a confirmed mutant, or are a citizen with higher clearance where such things could be overlooked.

Answer (score 5):

If you assign a Clearance Level to various forms of cybernetics you will have your answer. Treat it the same as registered mutants. Some of the Blue IntSec goons can openly flaunt their illegal mutations merely because they've wrangled some loophole and no one is willing to risk challenging them on it. Anything questionable is illegal until you have specific authorisation and even then you're in danger of any higher Clearance person or someone with high Access who decides to make your life difficult.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how this site works.  Happy gaming!